# Fedora 11, need help on how to read an incoming message automatically through gsm module in fedora 11

Tags: mysql, fedora, gsm

Im trying to access text message that comes from gsm module through fedora 11. I want to read the contents of the message and then use it to access the database which is scripted in MySQL((i.e) The message that I receive will be a number which is already available in the database). Is there any software specifically for fedora 11 which helps me to do this? Please help. This is my final year project.

Answer (score 0):

[smstools3](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/) might work.